# convert existing links to react router <Link to>?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When using react router, you must use the Link component for the links.
I want to convert an existing website to a reactjs web app.. the html is generated from the server and contains traditional  links... is there a way to convert these links into react router Link component?

Answer (score 2):

You can't literally translate them as they are outside the React scope.

You can use a different approach, you'll need two different tasks:

1. modifying the native (not React generated) link behavior by inserting custom event handlers
2. trigger a route change using code.

This can be done from React by using some Vanilla JS, something like

```
class MyComponent extentds React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      document.querySelectorAll('a.your_external_links').forEach((a) => {
        a.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
          ev.preventDefault();
          this.props.history.push("/new/url")
        });
      })
    }
}
```

Note the `querySelectorAll` call: you need to find a way to select all of your native links; you can perform this operation in multiple step (multiple `querySelector`, `querySelectorAll`, `getElementById` calls).

Final important note: **cleanup**!

You must remove new event listeners in the `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: and if I have declared a route for "/new/url", it should route it; right?

Comment: @yeahman yeah, this is the way it work. If you look at the `Link` implementation it's quite simple: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/f4081ae12e32788ac0580f83d1965cb69585d2d6/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js#L26